# Is it "since 1973, the festival has been running ... " or "since 1973, the festival has been run ..."

Tags: present-perfect, continuous-aspect

I had this in a test. I wrote the first one, "has been running" and got it wrong and the teacher wrote the second one, "has been run". I want to understand who's correct and why.

Comment: The festival has been running since 1973.  The festival has run every year since 1973.  We can't tell whether your first version is wrong without a hair more context.

Comment: Without knowing the full sentence it's impossible to say **who's** correct.

Comment: Woo 45 years long. It sounds like a pretty long festival. You don't mean it has been arranged once every year since then, or something similar?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you will need to supply more context. The two bits mean completely different things. Right now this amounts to asking which is correct between "I have a dog" and "I have a cat". On a separate note: why don't you just ask the teacher. They are your *teacher*. They have all the context, they know exactly why they changed it, and they are paid actual money to explain it to you. (Mind you, their reasoning can still be horribly wrong, but then we'll actually know what their reasoning *is*, and will be able to tell what exactly is wrong with it and why.)

Answer (score 11):

**Since 1973, the festival has been running every year.**

**Since 1973, the festival has been run by the town's entertainment committee.**

Both fragments that you wrote are incomplete, but not incorrect, and they can be completed in different ways. In "has been run", "run" is a passive form: (Active) The town's entertainment committee runs the festival. (Passive) The festival is run by the town's entertainment committee.

Unless you have been told *what* to express with your sentence, your answer is not wrong, and your teacher's answer is different, but no better.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to emphasize the *reason* these statements come across as incomplete.  If all you want to do is say "the festival has been run/running since 1973" (i.e. just the fact that that's how far back this festival's history goes) then you would say it in that order.  (And either "run" or "running" would be acceptable there I think.)  Moving "Since 1973" to the beginning creates the expectation that you are either (a) Yoda, or (b) making room to emphasize further details (how it has been running, by whom it has been run) at the end of the sentence.

Comment: “since 1973, the festival has been running” or “since 1973, the festival has been run" as a non-comercial festival (i forgot the word used)